# Plot a sinusoidal function with some parameters

Tags: plotting

I have the function

```
myfun[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, θ_, ϕ_] =
   a1 + 2 a2 + 3 a3 + b Cos[θ] + (a1 Cos[ϕ] + a2 Sin[ϕ]) Sin[θ];
```

The parameters satisfy $\sqrt{a1^2+a2^2+a3^2} + |b| \le 1$. I want to plot `myfun` with respect to $\theta$ and $\phi$. However, I want to do this for "various" combinations of the parameters $a1$,$a2$,$a3$ and $b$, satisfying above condition. Doing this by hand is very hard. Can we do this by Mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you mean:

First, initialize (I use := instead of your = )

```
Clear[myfun, plotfn]
myfun[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := a1 + 2 a2 + 3 a3 + b Cos[\[Theta]] + (a1 Cos[\[Phi]] + a2 Sin[\[Phi]]) Sin[\[Theta]]
```

Then, a plot function which plots what you ask for if the condition that you define is satisfied. Otherwise, it prints the result of the condition

```
plotfn[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_] /; (Sqrt[a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2] + Abs[b] <= 1) := 
ContourPlot[
myfun[a1, a2, a3, 
b, \[Tau], \[Phi]], {\[Tau], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \
\[Pi]}];
plotfn[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_] := 
"Sqrt[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(a1\), \
\(2\)]\)+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(a2\), \
\(2\)]\)+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(a3\), \(2\)]\)]+|b|" -> 
N[Sqrt[a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2] + Abs@b]
```

A Manipulate allows to vary a bit

```
Manipulate[
plotfn[\[Alpha]1, \[Alpha]2, \[Alpha]3, \[Beta]], {{\[Alpha]1, .1}, \
-1, 1}, {{\[Alpha]2, .1}, -1, 1}, {{\[Alpha]3, .1}, -1, 
1}, {{\[Beta], .1}, -1, 1}]
```

edit: forgot the Abs around b in the condition